# Logs not visible in Azure Custom Log

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

In my Azure portal, I created one "custom log", following this link [Custom Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-custom-logs)
, when I am trying to view the logs by searching(by my custom log name) in "Log Search" and running the run command I am not getting anything. Why? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: they are probably not being gathered

Comment: @4c74356b41, Hi, does it take time to gather? The file I uploaded is 2-3 kb file. I am running simple query of "Type=MY_LOG_NAME" in search bar. It is showing 0 result.

Comment: try doing `search *` and see if you can see your log type on the left panel

Comment: I tried that also as you said, its not showing any result.

Comment: they are not being uploaded for some reason, check you configuration

Comment: @4c74356b41, hi, yeah there were some configuration issues while connecting. I fixed those. Thanks for respose.

Comment: @Rudra Singh would you care to expand on "configuration issues"? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the reason for logs not appearing under custom logs was a configuration issue. When the issue was fixed the logs started appearing.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what kind of configuration issue you experienced ? It should help future visitors to fix their issue.

Comment: check the comments on the question. i have no idea, op fixed it without telling me